# How to share filtered data with same filter view in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using google spreadsheet and this is my code to import data and save my filter on it.

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {
  // Provide the full URL of the CSV file.
  var csvUrl = "https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // --- I added below script.
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  var range = filter.getRange();
  var criteria = [];
  var start = range.getColumn();
  var end = start + range.getNumColumns() - 1;
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    var criterion = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(i);
    if (criterion) criteria.push({col: i, c: criterion.copy()});
  }
  filter.remove();
  // ---

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  // And, I added below script.
  criteria.forEach(({col, c}) => range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(col, c));
}
```

My issue is: **How can i share the spreadsheet with my filter applied on it to use it ?**

In my case, I want to use another visualization tool on only filtered data

Comment: Can I confirm my understanding for your question? From `How to share filtered data with same filter view in google sheets?`, you want to use the filter view which is not the basic filter. And, in your goal, you want to retrieve the filtered values for using them to other tool. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike You are correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the case of the filter view, that depends on each user. By this, unfortunately, I think that in this case, your goal cannot be directly achieved. I think that when you use the basic filter, the filtered values can be retrieved. How about this? By the way, I think that your current script is for the basic filter. From this, I thought that you might be using the basic filter which is not the filter view. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, How to edit that script to my filter view? which is name: TestFilterSave

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm my understanding of your question. From your replying, I thought that you are using the filter view which is not the basic filter. About this, I cannot understand about your goal from `edit that script to my filter view`. I apologize for this. For example, you want to copy the filter view of `TestFilterSave` to other Google Spreadsheet? If my understanding is correct, in the current stage, unfortunately, the filter view cannot be activated by the script.